# How to find monotonous sequence in dataframe

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataframe in R say df

```
name <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o")
score <- c(42, 45, 47, 32,49,50, 51, 28, 54, 55, 56, 12, 13, 61, 64)
class <- c("c1", "c1", "c1", "c1","c1", "c2", "c2", "c2", "c2", "c2", "c3", "c3","c3", "c3", "c3")
df <- data.table(name, score, class)
```

It looks like :

```
df
     name score class
 1:    a    42    c1
 2:    b    45    c1
 3:    c    47    c1
 4:    d    32    c1
 5:    e    49    c1
 6:    f    50    c2
 7:    g    51    c2
 8:    h    28    c2
 9:    i    54    c2
10:    j    55    c2
11:    k    56    c3
12:    l    12    c3
13:    m    13    c3
14:    n    61    c3
15:    o    64    c3
```

I only require those records which follow a monotonous sequence of the score for each class. in this case only records with score 42, 45, 47, 49 for class c1, records with score 50, 51, 54, 55 for class c2, records with score 56, 61, 64 for class c3. I want to remove those records where score mentioned are not in sequence for each of the class c1, c2, c3. There are in total 1 million records.

Comment: first score have to taken as the starting reference in order to decide the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `diff`

```
df[c(TRUE, diff(score)>0)]
#    name score
#1:    a    42
#2:    b    45
#3:    c    47
#4:    e    50
#5:    f    51
```

#### Update

For the updated example in the OP's post

```
df[df[, .I[score == cummax(score)], class]$V1]
#    name score class
# 1:    a    42    c1
# 2:    b    45    c1
# 3:    c    47    c1
# 4:    e    49    c1
# 5:    f    50    c2
# 6:    g    51    c2
# 7:    i    54    c2
# 8:    j    55    c2
# 9:    k    56    c3
#10:    n    61    c3
#11:    o    64    c3
```

---

The same idea can be used with `base R`

```
df[with(df, ave(score, class, FUN = cummax)==score),]
#     name score class
# 1:    a    42    c1
# 2:    b    45    c1
# 3:    c    47    c1
# 4:    e    49    c1
# 5:    f    50    c2
# 6:    g    51    c2
# 7:    i    54    c2
# 8:    j    55    c2
# 9:    k    56    c3
#10:    n    61    c3
#11:    o    64    c3
```

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(class) %>%
   filter(score == cummax(score))
#    name score class
#   <chr> <dbl> <chr>
#1      a    42    c1
#2      b    45    c1
#3      c    47    c1
#4      e    49    c1
#5      f    50    c2
#6      g    51    c2
#7      i    54    c2
#8      j    55    c2
#9      k    56    c3
#10     n    61    c3
#11     o    64    c3
```

Comment: I want to do the same operation by each class, and there can be multiple out of sequence numbers, like in class c3, there are two out of sequence scores 12 and 13 and I don't want them too. please see the editted question

Comment: after applying your answer I am still getting the row with 13 as score as the difference in score 13-12 > 0 hence, record with 13 as score is still there, though that too is not desired as it is out of monotonous sequence.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `shift`-function:

```
df[shift(score, fill = 0) < score]
```

which gives:

```
   name score
1:    a    42
2:    b    45
3:    c    47
4:    e    50
5:    f    51
```

---

```
# create a larger dataset
dt <- data.table(name = sample(letters, 1e6, TRUE), score = sample(20:60, 1e6, TRUE))
```

A rudimentary benchmark a the larger dataset:

```
> system.time(dt[shift(score, fill = 0) < score])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.008   0.002   0.009 
> system.time(dt[dt[, .I[c(TRUE, diff(score)>0)]]])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.027   0.008   0.035 
> system.time(dt[c(TRUE, diff(score)>0)])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.020   0.003   0.023
```

---

As an alternative to @akrun's update for your updated example, you can also do:

```
df[, .SD[score == cummax(score)], class]
```

or with base R:

```
df[!!with(df, ave(score, class, FUN = function(x) x == cummax(x))), ]
```

Again a benchmark:

```
# create a larger dataset
dt <- data.table(name = sample(letters, 3e6, TRUE), 
                 score = sample(20:60, 3e6, TRUE), 
                 class = rep(c('c1','c2','c3'), each = 1e6))

# the benchmark

> system.time(dt[, .SD[score == cummax(score)], class])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.030   0.007   0.037 
> system.time(dt[dt[, .I[score == cummax(score)], class]$V1])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.028   0.007   0.035 
> system.time(dt[!!with(dt, ave(score, class, FUN = function(x) x == cummax(x))), ])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.158   0.076   0.236
```

Comment: I want to do the same operation by each class, and there can be multiple out of sequence numbers, please see the editted question

Comment: like in class c3, there are two out of sequence scores 12 and 13 and I don't want them too.

Comment: @Archit Akrun has already updated his answer, as alternative you can also do `df[, .SD[score == cummax(score)], class]` (but that might be a bit slower on a very large dataset)